# how to login and register a user using facebook

Tags: php, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, yii

I'm using Yii and Facebook JS SDK for user login / registration to my app.

Once i get the token back from facebook i'm sending an Ajax request to an internal function and validate this token against user email from facebook and login that user to my app using his email.

I wanted to know if this procedure is secured and is the proper way to login+register a user to my app using facebook.

Comment: Why cant you just use the login with facebook- the user will be registered with login. Why is all that register stuff needed?

Comment: the register part is needed because i want him to have an account in my app so he can login without facebook as well.
also i need to keep personal details + have a user entity that is in my system and not bound to facebook